# Outlook 2007 doesn't archive old email, only makes empty directory structures

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm trying to archive a lot of email from my inbox with a lot of subdirectories.

When I try to archive and select a date before 01-01-2008, the program says it will archive, the only thing is that the complete directory structure is archived without the email, can someone explain me why this is?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have this happen with Alt-N Mdeamon and Outlook. In this case it will only archive items according to when the cache was built and not when the email was originally created i.e. if you rebuild the cache today, and then you set your archive to archive anything over 1 month old, it will not archive a single thing until 1 month passes. Then it should sort itself out and just leave you 1 month of emails in the current directories. It seems to build the directory structure straight away regardless of this.
I do know that if you manually move the emails to the archive that this works.

And, I'm sorry if this doesn't apply to you in anyway!

Comment: Great answer, it looks indeed to the last day opened. When the email is openend recently, it will be flagged with an new date.

Answer (score 0):

Is your inbox an IMAP folder? Auto-archive fails miserably with IMAP folders in Outlook 2007, because it uses the last modified date rather than the date the message was received, and that's always the last time Outlook accessed the folder.

If you have shell access to the IMAP server or another linux box (or can induce a sysadmin to help you) you could configure Archivemail to do server-side automated archiving, which also has the advantage of not dumping the mail into a half-hidden PST file. (http://archivemail.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with archives/backups in Outlook 2007.  Without knowing if you're using IMAP or not, I would suggest that you should look at the MS KB article (below) on manually backing up/copying your .pst files which should maintain your complex subdirectory structure.  You can set your backup program to grab these files periodically.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287070

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "archiving" is enabled for the folder you want to archive.

To check that:

1. Choose the folder you wish to archive, then go to
2. **Folder** Tab and in *Properties* Group, click "**Folder Properties**"
3. **AutoArchive** Tab and select "**Archive items in this folder using the default settings**" or choose the option below if you have specific archiving requirements.